# Python 3 - Get text from tag in beautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am using beautifulSoup to extract data from website. Text from that website changes everytime you reload your page so basically I wish to be able to set a focus on the class name as a Static variable since the text is Dynamic.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
class2 = soup.find_all(True, class_="template_title")
print (class2)
```

which prints out
`<td align="left" class="template_title" height="50" valign="bottom" width="535"><div style="padding-bottom:9px;">4</div></td>`
When the page reloads, I will still have the focus on the area but I do not know how to print only the text (which in this case is : 4)

Once this is figured out, I have another question: If the class contains multiple tags, is there a way to get more static data to be sure it only prints the text I was searching for and not more? ( I have class, but could I use height="50" valign="bottom" width="535" as well?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use `text` or `string` attribute of the element.

   ```
   elems = soup.find_all(True, class_='template_title')
   print([elem.string for elem in elems])
   # prints `['4']` for the given html snippet
   ```
2. Specify more attributes as you want:

   ```
   elems = soup.find_all(True, class_='template_title',
                         height='50', valign='bottom', width='535')
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your help! But, lets say I print out the first time the sourcecode then I decide which tag I wish to focus on (the tag in my question). I do an input which asks the class name but if there is more than 1 tag in the class tag and I do not want to change my code to add the parameters. Is there a way for me to just copy paste the code I wish to keep (ex: class="template_title" height="50" valign="bottom" width="535") and it would place the parameters in place for the answer of my second question? I know my english is not on point but I do my best. Again, thank you for you answer :)

Comment: @bob, Instead of specifying as a keyword arguments, you can also pass the attributes as a dictionary: `soup.find_all(True, dict(class_='template_title', height='50', valign='bottom', width='535'))` if I understood your question.

Comment: Then how could I do it in here: `string_keep  = input("params to keep?: ") `     `class2 = soup.find_all(True, dict(string_keep)) `    
 `for x in class2:
    print (x.string) ` if my input is:  `class_="template_title", height="50", valign="bottom", width="535" ` I understand that it looks like my input is a string and not a dict, but how could I fix that? Meaning the user running the script could decide which param to keep, if that makes any sense

Comment: @bob, You need to parse the input and convert it into a dictionary. Could you post a separate question for that?

Comment: I tried to parse the parameters in a dict and it didn't work! When I used the sample of your question #2 it did work. I guess it is a problem with the dict function. Can you explain why it is like that and maybe how to fix it?

Comment: got it, on the documentation it said somewhere that we had to name the dict to attrs (probably attributes). So it looks like this: attrs={"class": "template_title","height":"50","valign":"bottom", "width":"535"})

Answer (score 0):

1. i usually use .get_text()
2. yes,you can

   there is a method : .find_all(name, attrs, recursive, string, limit, **kwargs)

   **kwargs ：recive anything like  height ,valign ,width

   or

   attrs = {'height':'50','valign':'bottom'}

Comment: Can you expand your answer? I am not sure to understand how they would work (maybe print a bit of code) Thank you for your answer :)