# Show text inside the tags BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to show only the text inside the tag, for example:

```
<span class="listing-row__price ">$71,996</span>
```

I want to only show

> "$71,996"

My code is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer

response = requests.get('https://www.cars.com/for-sale/searchresults.action/?mdId=21811&mkId=20024&page=1&perPage=100&rd=99999&searchSource=PAGINATION&showMore=false&sort=relevance&stkTypId=28880&zc=11209')

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

cars = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class': 'listing-row__price'})
print(cars)
```

How can I extract the text from the tags?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3 - Get text from tag in beautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31767897/python-3-get-text-from-tag-in-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To get the text within the tags, there are a couple of approaches,

a)  *Use the `.text`  attribute of the tag.*

```
cars = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class': 'listing-row__price'})
for tag in cars:
    print(tag.text.strip())
```

Output

```
$71,996
$75,831
$71,412
$75,476
....
```

b) *Use [get_text()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text)*

```
for tag in cars:
    print(tag.get_text().strip())
```

c) If there is *only that string inside the tag*, you can use these options also

- `.string`
- `.contents[0]`
- `next(tag.children)`
- `next(tag.strings)`
- `next(tag.stripped_strings)`

ie.

```
for tag in cars:
    print(tag.string.strip()) #or uncomment any of the below lines
    #print(tag.contents[0].strip())
    #print(next(tag.children).strip())
    #print(next(tag.strings).strip())
    #print(next(tag.stripped_strings))
```

Outputs:

```
$71,996
$75,831
$71,412
$75,476
$77,001
...
```

Note:

`.text` and `.string` are not the same. If there are other elements in the tag, `.string` returns the `None`, while .text will return the text inside the tag.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html="""
<p>hello <b>there</b></p>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
p = soup.find('p')
print(p.string)
print(p.text)
```

Outputs

```
None
hello there
```

Answer (score 3):

`print( [x.text for x in cars] )`

Answer (score 1):

Actually the `request` not returning any `response`. As I see, response code is `500` which means network issue and you are not getting any data.

What you are missing is `user-agent` which you need to send in `headers` along with `request`.

```
import requests
import re #regex library
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36"
}

crawl_url = 'https://www.cars.com/for-sale/searchresults.action/?mdId=21811&mkId=20024&page=1&perPage=100&rd=99999&searchSource=PAGINATION&showMore=false&sort=relevance&stkTypId=28880&zc=11209'
response = requests.get(crawl_url, headers=headers )


cars = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class': 'listing-row__price'})

for car in cars:
    print(re.sub(r'\s+', '', ''.join([car.text])))
```

#### output

```
$71,412  
$75,476  
$77,001  
$77,822  
$107,271 
...
```