# How to extract html text based on the lowest html tag level

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Is there a way to extract text with Beautifulsoup that is associated with the most relevant html tag? For example:

```
<div>
  I'm a div
  <p>I'm a paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Is there a way that I end up with

```
I'm a div
```

when getting the text from the div tag and I end up with:

```
I'm a paragraph
```

when getting the text from the p tag?

I've been working with the code below:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_description, 'html.parser')
TAGS_TO_APPEND = ['div', 'p', 'h1']
for tag in soup.find_all(True):
    if tag.name in TAGS_TO_APPEND:
        sanitised_description += tag.get_text(strip=True) + '\n\n' # Add two new lines for <p> tags
    elif tag.name == 'li':
        sanitised_description += '\n* ' + tag.get_text(strip=True)  # Add '*' for <li> tags
```

Because `tag.get_text()` returns all the text within the tag, ie I get "I'm a div I'm a paragraph" when looking at the div tag, I end up with duplicated texts. I also can't just get all the texts at the highest level because I need to reformat the text.

I've looked at multiple threads, one of them being: [Show text inside the tags BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54994297/show-text-inside-the-tags-beautifulsoup), but I don't think it's the same situation as I'm encountering for the solution provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `string=True` and `recursive=False` in `tag.find_all()`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = """\
<div>
  I'm a div
  <p>I'm a paragraph</p>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")
TAGS_TO_APPEND = ["div", "p", "h1"]

for tag in soup.find_all(TAGS_TO_APPEND):
    text = tag.find_all(string=True, recursive=False)
    text = " ".join(t for t in map(str.strip, text) if t)

    print("TAG  =", tag.name)
    print("TEXT =", text)
    print()
```

Prints:

```
TAG  = div
TEXT = I'm a div

TAG  = p
TEXT = I'm a paragraph
```